# HTC Sync Manager not recognizing One M8 after unlocking bootloader

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, backup, htc

I unlocked my boot loader and tried to restore from htc sync. nothing works. it recognizes for a split second and then says that update needed. this device needs to connect with the latest version of htc sync manager. please check for update or download. I am on the latest version. I'm panicking because I need my backed up data back. Please help